# Text hover > image show to have transition?

Tags: css

I have this code when on text hover, image pops, but can's succeed with setting transition to it. When I hover the image pops instantly without any transition.

```css
.link #img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -450%;
  left: 25%;
  display: none;
}

.link:hover #img {
  display: block;
}

#img {
  width: 160px;
  transition: 0.2s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Photography<img src="content/images/a.png" id="img"></a>
```

Comment: You can't animate `display`, you probably want some combination of `visibility` and `opacity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try with this code

use `visibility` or `opacity` and remove `top:-450%` from `css`

```css
.link #img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.link:hover #img {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

#img {
  width: 160px;
  transition: 0.5s linear;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Photography<img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/34950/pexels-photo.jpg" 
    id="img"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity or visibility` instead of `display`.

```css
.link #img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:150px;
  opacity:0;   
}
.link:hover #img {
  opacity:1;
}
#img {
  width:160px;    
  transition: 0.5s linear;    
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Photography<img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x200/000/fff" 
id="img"></a
```

Comment: Why would you waste your time answering with the same answer as that fellow above ?

Comment: Please see time. when I have submitted answer that time I know that someone has given answer.

Comment: @ankita_patel ahh, you are right, I underestimated the time it takes to write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little bit edit the code. Here is working version. Check it please.

Just for your knowledge - property **display** can't be affected by transition, because it has only two states: displayed and not displayed and no states in between, so transition is not working for this purpose.

Doog luck :)

```css
#img {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 160px;
  transition: all .3s ease;
}

.link:hover #img {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="link">Photography<img src="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-OowXWkgMSHI/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAANE/rOf2DCA2AXo/photo.jpg" id="img"></a>
```

Comment: How is this anything different than the other 2 answers ?

Comment: I removed excess CSS, for example.

Comment: @Yuriy_Popov the effort is much appreciated, but wouldn't an edit have been less time consuming for you ?